# Search result not showing in SP 2019 on-premise modern site to anonymous user

Tags: search-results, modern-experience, sharepoint-search, 2019, anonymous-access

The search result does not show when an anonymous user searches in SP 2019 on-premises modern site. Site is fully anonymous access enabled. I have done this literally 100s of times for classic. And it works for anonymous user if he searches from classic search page but the only problem comes when he searches from modern page.

**UPDATE**

Console errors before clicking in search text box on home page
[image]

Console errors after clicking in search text box on home page
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Search results are security trimmed, you need to ensure that anonymous users have at least read access to the file or item.

Comment: I have a SharePoint server 2019 (on-premises) Communication site (Modern UI). I have set anonymous access. Anonymous users can view all pages. when redirecting to the search page it shows a blank page, even it does not show search control. On the other hand, I just have to check the results in a classic search. And the results show up for anonymous users. So, I think it is not an access issue. Any idea what's wrong with modern search 2019 on-premises.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when an anonymous user loads the search page? I'm guessing they don't have access to specific client side assets that the modern page relies on.

Comment: I am facing the similar problem. There is no access issue. It's just that if it is searched from modern UI -> no results, nothing. If on the same site, searched from classic UI -> works great.

Comment: Have you confirmed that there are no errors in the console when viewed as an anonymous user? As mentioned previously, it's possible that anonymous users do not have access to the JavaScript assets required for the modern search page to work.

Comment: @CallumCrowley, yes, there are errors about failing to load the resources (search js files) https://gyazo.com/9a371346de0e6a96887b7372f259a895 
https://gyazo.com/38bba91e38918af0ea9b3f92d5efd07b 
What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you should attempt to resolve this yourself or put a support request in to Microsoft. If the modern SharePoint is supported with anonymous users is supported (which I don't know), then you should probably put a support ticket in with Microsoft.

Comment: @Aks I’m looking at the errors in your posted image, the Anonymous users are not getting results cuz the search api calls are impersonating the user, not the Search Service/Principal.  After personally going through the ‘Add a permission level’ process, there is no option to allow api access, so it may not be enumerable - at least in the UI.  My suggestion is to attempt to create a custom modern search results page, if possible:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-search-blog/creating-custom-search-results-pages-in-sharepoint-online/ba-p/1141515  (article is for SPO, maybe 2019)

Comment: @CallumCrowley I have been thinking the same that maybe the modern search isn't supposed to be for the anonymous users. I will look into it some more. Thanks!

Comment: @A.k.A.Fritz Really appreciate you taking time to look into this. And yes, no option for allowing the search api to anonymous users. I will check the custom search web parts. It's a good idea. Thanks!